# How to get the text of an etherpad in the padUpdate hook of a plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, etherpad

Im writing a plugin for etherpad. I am implementing the [`padUpdate`](https://etherpad.org/doc/latest/#index_padupdate) hook and would like to know the contents of the pad.

This is my handler in the index.js of the plugin:

```js
exports.padUpdate = function (hook_name, context) {
    // get text of pad
    const text = ...;
    
    processText(text);
};
```

Documentation says:
Things in context:

1. pad - the pad instance
2. author - the id of the author who updated the pad
3. revs - the index of the new revision
4. changeset - the changeset of this revision (see Changeset Library)

And there is a function [`getText(padID, [rev])`](https://etherpad.org/doc/latest/#index_gettext_padid_rev). My first idea was to get the pad ID from context and call `getText(padID)`, but I don't know on which object to call `getText(padID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```js
exports.padUpdate = function (hook_name, context) {
    const text = context.pad.atext.text;

    processText(text);
};
```